# Check odd number of a certain character

Tags: regex

For Uni, I need to write a method with a string as parameter which checks if the string has an even number of a's in it. Normally I had sequences like this:
baaaaaad which would then be easy to figured out by RegEx `(.*)(aa)*(.*)`
But now they look like this:

```
baadaafaag
```

And I have no clue how to do this since there are other characters seperating this.

Comment: Try `^(?:[^a]*a[^a]*a)*[^a]*$`

Answer (score 1):

Try this one for a simpler solution

```
^([^a]*(a{2})*[^a]*)*$
```

It checks for groups of 2 "a"s delimited by non-"a"s

```
bad             no match
baad            match
baaad           no match
baaaad          match
baaaaad         no match
baaaaaad        match
baadaafaag      match
baadaaaaag      no match
```

Answer (score 0):

just use this `[a-z]*aa+[a-z]*aa+[a-z]*`

Here `[a-z]*` for zero or more character.`aa+` for atleast 1 `a` followed by `a`that means `aa`.
The inner `[a-z]*` is for you may or may having have any number of character between every fair of `aa`.

Outer `[a-z]*` for you may have any number of character after `aa`.